# How to make a product with license edition

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a java spring boot project. I have requirement to make it standard and enterprise. Standard version will have only basic features, And Enterprise version will have all features(basic
+ complex). At deployment time (its an OVF file) I will have an option to check if it should be deployed as standard or enterprise. So basically based on a flag i need to decide the version. How do i enable or disable some features based on a flag (true/false). I have heard about @interface annotation, but am not sure how it works. Please  guide . Thank you

Comment: How can you access this flag? Is it an environment variable or a system property?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli flag is a environment variable, which will be set true or false during deployment of OVF file.